# differences between different noun forms of same adjective

Tags: grammar, nouns

What is exactly the difference between nouning an adjective different ways? Some only have one form, but others have both. Examples:

- hilarious: **hilarity** vs. **hilariousness**
- virtuous: **virtuosity** vs. **virtuousness**
- clandestine: **clandestinity** vs. **clandestineness**

As an aside, what causes some to only have one form, like cheap --> **cheapness**, and what causes others to have two? And some have none, it seems. For example, accomplished --> * **accomplishedness**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suffixes -*ness* and -*ity* are roughly synonymous, but they have different etymologies.

> There are two **roughly synonymous
>   suffixes**, -*ness* and -*ity*, which
>   are typically used for forming
>   abstract nouns from adjectives, as in
>   example below.
>
> - generous + -*ness* = generousness
> - generous + -*ity* = generosity
>
> **The first suffix, -*ness*, is
>   etymologically native, while -*ity*
>   entered the language as a result of
>   contact with French during the Middle
>   English period.**

(..)

> In addition, the meaning of words in
>   -*ity* is often not entirely compositional, i.e., not deductible
>   from the meanings of the base and the
>   suffix. Thus, it is both
>   phonologically and semantically more
>   opaque than -*ness* (cf. Riddle 1985:
>   443–444; Aronoff and Anshen 1998:
>   246).

This was extracted from the article [PRODUCTIVITY OF THE SUFFIXES -NESS AND -ITY
IN 17TH-CENTURY ENGLISH LETTERS: A SOCIOLINGUISTIC APPROACH](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CC8QFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Foa.doria.fi%2Fbitstream%2Fhandle%2F10024%2F42336%2Fproducti.pdf%3Fsequence%3D3&rct=j&q=ness%20ity%20suffix&ei=I5K4TPDPFtaSjAfLxMThDg&usg=AFQjCNHTQZEtf_7oygHtOSJC3hsFivOoyg&sig2=cC0HE_PlJCPiV15Sl7ompA&cad=rja).

Comment: true about the 2nd part. "hilarity" often means like general funniness/a funny situation (hilarity ensues), but "hilariousness" would mean more closely the hilarious quality of something.

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ness) explains the -ness suffix rather well, and links to several other suffixes, several of which are often used to make an adjective into a noun.

As for accomplished, it is the past tense of the verb accomplish.

Comment: It's a good idea to (whenever possible) include at least a little information here in the answer itself, rather than leaving just a link. (Especially when the link is to a user-editable websites like Wiktionary, whose content may change at any time.) (BTW, on many wiki sites you can click on "Permanent link" in the left column to link to the version of the page you read: in this case, it's [this one](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=-ness&oldid=9328268).)

Comment: All that said, I don't think the link you gave contains a good answer to this question. :-)

Comment: *Accomplished* is both the past participle of the verb *accomplish* and an adjective: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accomplished.  You can attach *-ness* to many adjectives even if they are formed from past participles of verbs, e.g. *tiredness*: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiredness