# How to say "the quality of being accomplished"?

Tags: single-word-requests, morphology

"to tire" is to become exhausted. "tired" means exhausted. "tiredness" is the state of being exhausted. Similarly, "to accomplish" means to complete a goal (let's say), "accomplished" means completed, "*accomplishedness" is the state of being accomplished? What should go there?

More generally, how do you noun adjectives that you can't add `-ness` to? Related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4068/differences-between-different-noun-forms-of-same-adjective).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on context, I would go with *completeness*, *perfection*, *accomplishment*, *achievement* or *consummation*. Or even an idiom such as *being home and dry; in the bag; signed and sealed; wrapped up; signed, sealed, delivered*.

To answer the general question of how I would noun adjectives that I can't add -ness to, I wouldn't noun them simply for the sake of nouning. I'd just look for an existing synonym.

Comment: @Steve: to be fair, Claudiu started it. I refuse to take credit for his achievements in verbing. (^_^)

Comment: noun is a great verb =).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when referring to an action that has been accomplished, a synonym such as "completed" is used.

Alternatively, you could render it with a phrase similar to, "having been accomplished..."

Rendering verbs as nouns (more properly referred to as gerund forms, IIRC) is tricky business in English, given the number of irregular constructions that the language is burdened with.  It's probably best, if you have any doubts, to use an equivalent phrase.  While it may not be the most ideal or concise way of going about things, using a phrase is often a safer choice.